# How do I get the RAW message with a jax-ws client?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I am trying to get the raw XML response from a web service instead of the parsed soap version.

I am using a jax-ws client that has been generated with org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava. The issue is sometimes the webservice returns an HTML error and the soap parsing fails and I get the following in the logs:

```
 Response was of unexpected text/html ContentType.  Incoming portion of HTML stream: System.ArgumentException: Chunked encoding must be set via the Sen
dChunked property.
Parameter name: value
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_TransferEncoding(String value)
   at MultiversionRouter.Routers.BaseRequestRouter.RouteRequest(HttpContext app, AsyncCallback callback, WebResponse& errorResponse)
   at MultiversionRouter.RouteProviderHandler.beginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
2015-07-02 08:58:51,054 [Thread-63063        ] javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: Response was of unexpected text/html ContentType.  Incoming portion of HTML stream: System.ArgumentException: Chunked encoding must be set via the SendChunked property.
Parameter name: value
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_TransferEncoding(String value)
   at MultiversionRouter.Routers.BaseRequestRouter.RouteRequest(HttpContext app, AsyncCallback callback, WebResponse& errorResponse)
   at MultiversionRouter.RouteProviderHandler.beginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:157)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.updateServiceTicketViaManagedId(Unknown Source)
    at com.nable.libpsa.ConnectWiseProxy.updateTicket(ConnectWiseProxy.java:538)
    at com.nable.libpsa.ConnectWiseProxy.run(ConnectWiseProxy.java:1591)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Response was of unexpected text/html ContentType.  Incoming portion of HTML stream: System.ArgumentException: Chunked encoding must be set via the SendChunked property.
Parameter name: value
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_TransferEncoding(String value)
   at MultiversionRouter.Routers.BaseRequestRouter.RouteRequest(HttpContext app, AsyncCallback callback, WebResponse& errorResponse)
   at MultiversionRouter.RouteProviderHandler.beginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxInInterceptor.handleMessage(StaxInInterceptor.java:84)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:835)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1614)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1504)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1310)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:628)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:565)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:474)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:377)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:330)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:135)
    ... 4 more
```

I have tried using javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler but it never gets to this point when we get this error, It works perfectly fine on successful calls.

Comment: Well I have not been successful in Java I was able to get a more clear message using SoapUI:
System.ArgumentException: Chunked encoding must be set via the SendChunked property.
Parameter name: value
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_TransferEncoding(String value)
   at MultiversionRouter.Routers.BaseRequestRouter.RouteRequest(HttpContext app, AsyncCallback callback, WebResponse& errorResponse)
   at MultiversionRouter.RouteProviderHandler.beginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)

Answer (score 2):

Please use:

**javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler**

You can get message using SOAPMessageContext, method getMessage() and convert the message to a String.

Sample code:

```
public static String getXmlMessage(SOAPMessage message) throws Exception
   {
         ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         message.writeTo(os);
         final String encoding = (String) message.getProperty(SOAPMessage.CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING);
         if (encoding == null)
         {
             return new String(os.toByteArray());
         }
         else
         {
            return new String(os.toByteArray(), encoding);    
         }
   }
```

Comment: I do exactly that, the problem is it fails before that handler gets a chance because it is not being parsed properly into a SOAPMessage to be passed to that method.